# The path was messed up after nested routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I really have no clue why it happen.

this is my routes

```
resources :users do
    resources :bookmarks
end
```

Controller

```
# bookmarks_controller
def edit 
    # this returns perfectly data in the edit view
    @bookmark = current_user.bookmarks.find(params[:id])
end
```

This is the view

```
<%= form_for @bookmark do |b| %>
<% end %>
```

Since everything messed up when I nested the bookmarks resources inside users it causes the error

**undefined method `bookmark_path'**

Then I change the form to

```
<%= form_for user_bookmark_path(current_user, @bookmark) do |b| %>
```

The error is gone but there is no such data in the text field form, and the form action is **/users/[user_id]/bookmarks/[bookmark_id]/edit**

rake routes info

```
user_bookmarks     GET    /users/:user_id/bookmarks(.:format)          bookmarks#index
                   POST   /users/:user_id/bookmarks(.:format)          bookmarks#create
new_user_bookmark  GET    /users/:user_id/bookmarks/new(.:format)      bookmarks#new
edit_user_bookmark GET    /users/:user_id/bookmarks/:id/edit(.:format) bookmarks#edit
user_bookmark      GET    /users/:user_id/bookmarks/:id(.:format)      bookmarks#show
                   PUT    /users/:user_id/bookmarks/:id(.:format)      bookmarks#update
                   DELETE /users/:user_id/bookmarks/:id(.:format)      bookmarks#destroy
```

Any idea how to fix it ? Thanks

Comment: Just saying: `current_user.bookmarks.find(params[:id])` will generate 2 queries to the DB. You know the bookmark id, why not finding it directly (and test ownership after) like this: `Bookmark.where(id: params[:id], user_id: current_user.id)`? This does only 1 query to the DB ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like:

```
<%= form_for [current_user, @bookmark] do |b| %>
<% end %>
```